# Close modal on click outside of the modal JS on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, modal-dialog

How do I make this code `close` a `modal` when user clicks outside of the modal window both on **iOS** and non-touch devices?

I know about some other similar topics here regarding `window.onclick` and `touch` devices, but I'm relatively new to JS and I don't know how to properly combine this function (for both platforms).

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
var closeModal = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('touchend', closeModal);
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 100%;
}
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 70%;
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<span class="close">&times;</span>

<p>Some content here</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind `touchend` and `click` event to the window element:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var state = 'closed';

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        state = 'open';
    }, 300);
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

var closeModal = function(event) {
    var closest = event.target.closest('#myModal');
  
    if ((null === closest || 0 < closest.length) && 'open' === state) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        state = 'closed';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('touchend', closeModal);
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 100%;
}
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 70%;
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">open</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<span class="close">&times;</span>

<p>Some content here</p>

</div>
```

**Edit:** Updated code snippet.

On that solution i added simple a state to run close method only when state is `open`. With the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method we search over all parent of the clicked element if there is a element that is equal to `modal`.

Only when `closest` is null or has a length of 0 we will close the modal.

Comment: Do you get some exceptions? Otherwise can you add a html structure to the snippet on your question? I need some working example to continue to help you.

Comment: Here is the [source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom)

Comment: It works with my solution on my iPhone with iOS 12. See here: [Solution](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVN9VXB0Y8SM)

Comment: Yes W3 example is working as expected, but not in my case, I updated the question

Comment: There must be some other stuff when W3 example works but not on your website. Your code on the question looks fine, only my change for touch devices is missing. Do you have some other code on your website that will block touch-events?

Comment: I added your code into the question snippet, no, nothing should block touch events on page

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! ps: why do you chose for this case `touchend` instead of `touchstart`?

Comment: 1. Because a click-event also be thrown when the mouse-button has been released. 2. With the touchstart event the modal will be closed when you will start to scroll outside the modal.